# iOS Download image from iCloud

Tags: ios, phasset

I have written like this to select photo.

```
- (void)assetsPickerController:(CTAssetsPickerController *)picker didFinishPickingAssets:(NSArray *)assets
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"videos %@",assets);

    for (PHAsset* asset in assets)
    {
        if (asset.mediaType == 2)
        {
            [self addVideoToMediaContainerWithAsset:asset];
        }
        else
        {

            PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];

            [manager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                              contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                                  options:self.requestOptions
                            resultHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info){

                                if (self.isToSelectSingleImage) {
                                self.mediaCollection = [NSMutableArray array];
                                self.thumbnailCollection = [NSMutableArray array];
                                }
                                [self addImageToMediaContainerWithImage:image.normalizedImage];
                            }];
        }

    }

}
```

But problem is that if image is from iCloud, it is nil and when I output info, I saw like this.

```
(lldb) po info {
    PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 9999;
    PHImageResultIsDegradedKey = 0;
    PHImageResultIsInCloudKey = 1;
    PHImageResultIsPlaceholderKey = 0;
    PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 9999; }
```

I am finding solution in stackoverflow and github. But I don't know how to download that image. How shall I do?